# Vaadin TwinColSelect remove items from option column without removing selected column values

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a situation where the user is prompted with a twin column selector. The options column is populated based on a selection of a combo box.

So, I need "options list" to change based on combo box selection. But I want the selected values to remain the same.

```
eg. combo box value = international
options column is populated international with users. 

combo box value = local
options column is populated with local users.
```

At the end, when I collecting the selected values, it may contain both local and international users.

Something like this:

```
twinColSelect.removeAllFromLeft();
twinColSelect.addItemsToLeft(internationlUsersList);
```

How do I achieve this? I tried the following approach; somehow I can get the selected values from the code. But from the frontend I can only see is selected values from the current options list.

```
myComboBox.addValueChangeListener(event1 -> {

    Object value = twinColSelect.getValue();
    twinColSelect.removeAllItems();
    myComboBox.getValue.getUsers().forEach(ob -> twinColSelect.addItem(ob.getUserName()));
    twinColSelect.setValue(value);
});
```

Comment: It's not clear. What should happen? What happens instead?

Comment: Options column (left) should be able to update without changing anything from the right column.

Comment: Impossible. How can a value be selected if it's not in the available ones?

Comment: That's what I thought. :)

Comment: I wonder what happens when you use a container data source for your TwinColSelect that supports filtering. The filter could be set according to your combo box value. I am curious what happens with the selected values of the TwinColSelect when they are filtered out.

Comment: I tried that but as soon as adding a filter to the container, both the source and the selected list are filtered. So I guess you need to implement a TwinColSelect on your own for the special behavior.

Comment: I found a workaround. It's not perfect, but it gets the job done.  
this is what I did, before removing all items, I saved the selected values. Then remove all items. After that, I added my new values and saved selected values to the item list. Then it was possible to set selected values to the list. :)

Comment: Ok, can you post it as answer for future reference?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. It's not perfect, but it gets the job done.

This is what I did, before removing all items, I saved the selected values.
Then remove all items. After that, I added my 'new values' and previously saved 'selected values' to the item list.

Then it was possible to set selected values to the list

```
Object selectedValues=twinSelect.getValue();

twinSelect.removeAllItems();

twinSelect.addItems(newITemsList);

(Collection<?>selectedValues.forEach(o ->twinSelect.addItem(o));

twinSelect.setValue(selectedValues);
```